# R Find common set of multiple IDs that maximize intersection

Tags: r, merge, match, intersection

I have several layers of data (a,b,c,etc...) collected on the same individuals but with two types of IDs for each individual that can differ between datasets.
I need to merge these datasets by either types of IDs, ID1 or ID2, to match the maximum number of records.

```
a_ID1=c("rs1", "rs2", "rs10", "rs35")
a_ID2=c("zzz", "xxx", "fff", "aaa")
df1 = data.frame(ID1=a_ID1, ID2=a_ID2, x=c(1,2,3,4))

b_ID1=c("rs1", "rs2", "rs10", "rs35")
b_ID2=c("ttt", "yyy", "eee", "aaa")
df2 = data.frame(ID1=b_ID1, ID2=b_ID2, x=c(7,8,9,10))

c_ID1=c("rs3", "rs5", "rs6", "rs444")
c_ID2=c("zzz", "xxx", "eee", "www")
df3 = data.frame(ID1=c_ID1, ID2=c_ID2, x=c(40,41,42,43))
```

this is what I am trying to get to, but I do not know in advance which of the combinations of IDs will match the most number of records...

```
merge(df3, merge(df1, df2, by="ID1"), by.x="ID2", by.y="ID2.x")
```

I could test each combination of each data frames' `ID1` and `ID2` to first find the combination that has the largest intersect, and then merge each pairwise data, but is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks so much for any ideas!

Comment: Create a hash for the first set, iterate over the rest and count duplicates? Do you know the levels of the IDs?

Comment: thanks shayaa, no I don't know a priori...

Comment: I guess the best way would be to first find the best combinations pairwise ?  match_df1 = which.max(c(length(df1$ID1[df1$ID1 %in% df2$ID1]), length(df1$ID2[df1$ID2 %in% df2$ID1]))); match_df2 = which.max(c(length(df2$ID1[df2$ID1 %in% df1$ID1]), length(df2$ID2[df2$ID2 %in% df1$ID1]))); merge(df1, df2, by.x=names(df1)[match_df1], by.y=names(df1)[match_df2])